# JQueryEventObject & target

Tags: typescript

In an event handler I need to determine the DOM Element which got clicked.  I would expect to use jqEvent.target.attributes['tag'] where jqEvent is of type JQueryEventObject.  But 'target' is defined in lib.d.ts as of type EventTarget which contains nothing I can use...

Have I missed something?

Comment: lib.d.ts like any declaration file isn't the final word on what's going to happen.  If jqEvent really is of type JQueryEventObject you can always cast it.

Answer (score 5):

I use this and it works fine...

```
    private funct(event: JQueryEventObject) {
        var state = $(event.target).prop('checked');
    }
```

Comment: More info on the `$event` parameter: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-

Comment: @rinogo We are talking about JQuery, not Angular... :D

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Matěj Pokorný!  FWIW, Angular still uses "jqLite" (or full jQuery if its loaded), so this is still relevant.  Your answer helped me with my Angular-based Typescript, so thanks! :)  I'll leave my link in case it helps any of the Angular peeps who hit this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of `EventTarget` (found in `dom.generated.d.ts`, distributed with TypeScript):

```
interface EventTarget {
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListener, useCapture?: boolean): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListener, useCapture?: boolean): void;
    dispatchEvent(evt: Event): boolean;
}
```

There could be other classes that implement `EventTarget` in order to attach events, so the safest API definition is to set `Event.target` to the object that implements `EventTarget` where the listeners are attached.

In the jQuery context, `Event.target` will almost certainly be of type `HTMLElement` (not type `JQuery` as in Andree's answer). For your example of `jqEvent.target.attributes['tag']`, the correct way is to notify the compiler that it is actually a `Node` (grandparent interface of `HTMLElement`), which does have the `attributes` property:

```
(<Node> jqEvent.target).attributes['tag']
```

The above cast could also be to `HTMLElement` if you are explicitly accessing properties of the more specific interface. Using the most general interface possible is considered object-oriented best practice.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is actually a mistake in the declaration. It's supposed to be of type JQuery. But is can be  casted either by Typescript construct

```
<JQuery>(event.target)[0].attributes['id'];
```

or as a parameter to the constructor to JQuery

```
$(event.target)[0].attributes['id'];
```

Comment: This is close, but technically incorrect.  ["The object is an instance of a jQuery Event Object when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object."](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)